# jQuery unrecognized in a view that is generated using @Html.Raw

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I have a Razor view that has jQuery included and the JavaScript function on this view recognizes jQuery. I also have multiple div elements that contain other view html within this view using something like

```
@foreach(Record record in records)
{
    <div>@Html.Raw(record.RecordHtml)</div>
}
```

If I include a JavaScript function inside of the foreach with the div, it fails to recognize jQuery.

```
    @foreach(Record record in records)
    {
        <div>@Html.Raw(record.RecordHtml)</div>
        <script>            
            function getElement()
            {
                $("#recordId");
            }
        </script>
    }
```

The work around for this is to include jQuery in each iteration, but I don't understand why this is needed if jQuery is already included on the primary view.

Can someone explain why each div needs its own jQuery include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstaning.
There definately does not need to be a jquery include in every iteration.
To prove it, change your code to

```
 <script src="path/to/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 @foreach(Record record in records)
    {
        <div>@Html.Raw(record.RecordHtml)</div>
        <script>            
            function getElement()
            {
                $("#recordId");
            }
        </script>
    }
```

Notice, jquery is explicitly included before the for loop.

The real problem here is jquery is not loaded before those scripts are inserted. Yes, jQuery may eventually be loaded.

But, you need to review the order of loading and use of master and partial layouts to ensure jQuery is loaded before.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, by following this suggestion I was able to see that the problem was not with the include statement at all. The problem was related to switching versions of jQuery and changing the structure of the solution as well as outdated view code being saved and retrieved from a database.